# opentelemetry-python + opentelemetry-collector prometheus，metrics has different datas，use uWSGI or gunicorn running multiple workers

Tags: python, prometheus, gunicorn, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

### describe

As a Python beginner, I sincerely seek guidance

i use opentelemetry-python to metrics my python project HTTP meter manually, it runs with **gunicorn**, and send metrics data to opentelemetry-exporter

but i find opentelemetry-exporter receive mutiple data with different gunicorn workders

with the following content:

### 1、OTLP exporters

OTLP exporters  ,  receives data and export to **prometheus**

a file called collector-config.yaml with the following content:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317

processors:
  memory_limiter:
    check_interval: 5s
    limit_percentage: 85
    spike_limit_percentage: 25

  batch/metrics:
    timeout: 200ms
    send_batch_size: 8192
    send_batch_max_size: 8192
exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8073"
    resource_to_telemetry_conversion:
      enabled: false

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [memory_limiter, batch/metrics]
      exporters: [prometheus]
```

### 2、my flask web demo

sdk :

```
class OtlpConfig:
    def __init__(self):

        endpoint = os.getenv(OTLP_EXPORTER_ENDPOINT) or os.getenv(
            OTLP_EXPORTER_ENDPOINT.lower()) or os.getenv(
            OTLP_EXPORTER_ENDPOINT.lower().replace('_', '.')) or "http://127.0.0.1:4317"

        metrics_exporter = OTLPMetricExporterGRPC(endpoint)

        reader = PeriodicExportingMetricReader(exporter=metrics_exporter, export_interval_millis=15,
                                               export_timeout_millis=5)

        meter_provider = MeterProvider(
            metric_readers=[reader]

        )
        metrics.set_meter_provider(meter_provider)
        meter = metrics.get_meter(name="flyme-fcop-python-meter-sdk")
        self.meter = meter

        logging.info("Starting OTLP successfully")

    def get_meter(self):
        return self.meter
```

Use gunicorn start the parameter, use two workers

```
gunicorn --workers=2 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 main:app
```

it will run with 2 workers:

```
2024-03-21 10:15:55 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2024-03-21 10:15:55 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2024-03-21 10:15:55 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2024-03-21 10:15:55 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2024-03-21 10:15:55 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2024-03-21 10:15:55 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
```

and i request my metrics http address  3 times, OtlpConfig was initialized twice because of 2 workers .

i request my app 3 time totally , 1 request fell on the  workers  pid: 8 ， 2 request fell on the  workers  pid: 9

**but opentelemetry-exporter receive mutiple data with different gunicorn workers**

**The prometheus data display may different , depending on the number of visits to the same address ,  as follow:**

http://127.0.0.1:8073/metrics   the  first time requests :

```
http_server_request_seconds_sum{job="unknown_service",url="/three/app/process"} 0.30804229132064576
http_server_request_seconds_count{job="unknown_service",url="/three/app/process"} 1
```

http://127.0.0.1:8073/metrics  the second time requests

```
http_server_request_seconds_sum{job="unknown_service",url="/three/app/process"} 0.5080454164143
http_server_request_seconds_count{job="unknown_service",url="/three/app/process"} 2
```

when prometheus pull the opentelemetry-exporter data, it will has some miscalculation, time series look like up and down,

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5FqY.png)

normal data like this :

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1PuT.png)

### question

1、Does opentelemetry-exporter receives data groupy by workers by default ? Does opentelemetry-exporter  has some aggregations plugin to resolve ?

2、If do not have solution , i will try to use workers id append to my metrics tag , so i can distinguish this data, but data will delay reporting ,  because  prometheus  server only  pull {workders} * {interval} times can get all metrics.

3、prometheus python client suggest use multiprocess https://prometheus.github.io/client_python/multiprocess/

and  opentelemetry suggest https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/metrics/data-model/#overlap-resolution

have everybody encountered?

---

I am eager to learn from the seasoned individuals here and would be grateful for any guidance or solutions provided. Thank you all, esteemed experts, for your invaluable assistance!